# What do you suggest on how to stop hit counter for the same IP in asp.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As you can see on the question, what is your advice about stoping hit counter for the same ip in ASP.NET web site ?

Im my real estate project i increase the view count of a property when it is viewed. But i just want to increase it only if the user has a different ip. If the user refresh the page, the hit counter shouldn't be increased.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about having a hit counter that only counts unique views (only counts one view from each IP)?

Comment: If so, who made the hit counter..

Comment: You really need to elaborate, perhaps post some code?

Comment: i am very sorry, it is about English, i wanted to mean hit counter for a web site. Yes i am talking about having a hit counter that only counts unique views.

Sorry again, i will edit the question

Comment: Rather than writing your own, have you checked Google Analytics? Very good for counting new vs. existing visitors, plus a whole bunch of other nice counters.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, i am using analytics already. I am holding the number of views of a Property in an Estate project, so i dont want user to press F5 or refresh the page for increasing the view count of the Property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a website you can be a little more accurate counting unique visitors by dropping a cookie containing the date & time.  Check the cookie, if it exists and the date is today don't add one to the counter.